# MySQL - Update rows where value in column is the same as previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to clean up some incorrect data:

```
id   |   name
-------------
1    |   C
2    |   A
3    |   A
4    |   B
5    |   B
6    |   B
7    |   B
8    |   X
9    |   X
10   |   A   
11   |   A      
12   |   A
13   |   X
14   |   X
15   |   B
16   |   C
17   |   C
18   |   X
19   |   A
20   |   A
```

What has happened is when the data has been entered, if the `name` field was NULL, the value from the previous iteration of a loop has not been cleared so it has been entered into the next row.

The data should look like this:

```
id   |   name
-------------
1    |   C
2    |   A
3    |   NULL
4    |   B
5    |   NULL
6    |   NULL
7    |   NULL
8    |   X
9    |   NULL
10   |   A   
11   |   NULL     
12   |   NULL
13   |   X
14   |   NULL
15   |   B
16   |   C
17   |   NULL
18   |   X
19   |   A
20   |   NULL
```

Is there a way I can update the entire table in one swoop by setting all duplicates like this to NULL, while preserving the values where the column had an intended value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to join our duplicates into chain, it easy to reach by:

```
select *
from updateTable t1
left join updateTable t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id+1 = t2.id
;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | name | id   | name |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | C    | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | A    |    3 | A    |
|  3 | A    | NULL | NULL |
|  4 | B    |    5 | B    |
|  5 | B    |    6 | B    |
|  6 | B    |    7 | B    |
|  7 | B    | NULL | NULL |
|  8 | X    |    9 | X    |
|  9 | X    | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | A    |   11 | A    |
| 11 | A    |   12 | A    |
| 12 | A    | NULL | NULL |
| 13 | X    |   14 | X    |
| 14 | X    | NULL | NULL |
| 15 | B    | NULL | NULL |
| 16 | C    |   17 | C    |
| 17 | C    | NULL | NULL |
| 18 | X    | NULL | NULL |
| 19 | A    |   20 | A    |
| 20 | A    | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Now we know our ids that should be updated.

But we cannot run:

```
update updateTable set name = null where id in (
    select t2.id
    from updateTable t1
    left join updateTable t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id+1 = t2.id
    where t2.id is not null
);
```

because we will receive error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'updateTable' for update in FROM clause
```

but we can avoid this bug by using temporary table for ids:

```
create temporary table updateTableTmp (
    id int,
    primary key (id)
) engine=innodb;

insert into updateTableTmp
select t2.id
from updateTable t1
left join updateTable t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id+1 = t2.id
where t2.id is not null
;

update updateTable set name = null where id in (
    select id from updateTableTmp
);

select * from updateTable;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | C    |
|  2 | A    |
|  3 | NULL |
|  4 | B    |
|  5 | NULL |
|  6 | NULL |
|  7 | NULL |
|  8 | X    |
|  9 | NULL |
| 10 | A    |
| 11 | NULL |
| 12 | NULL |
| 13 | X    |
| 14 | NULL |
| 15 | B    |
| 16 | C    |
| 17 | NULL |
| 18 | X    |
| 19 | A    |
| 20 | NULL |
+----+------+
```

Comment: What about non consecutive ids?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. And thanks for showing the test data.

Answer (score 0):

User variables to mimic a row number per each name.Tested on my machine

```
SELECT @var:=name,@no:=0 FROM t ORDER BY id;
UPDATE t join
(select ID,NAME,(CASE WHEN NAME=@var THEN @no:=@no+1 ELSE @no:=1 AND @var:=NAME END) BLAH
from T
order by ID)X
on T.ID=X.ID
SET T.NAME= NULL
where X.BLAH<>0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have very simple and straight forward solution.

Just get the first record of each, ignore it in update. 
The query will looks like this:

```
UPDATE table SET name = NULL WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'A' LIMIT 1 )
```